# Given a required confidence, what is the original number required?

Tags: probability

I need to pick 12.5% out of a set of equal number of male and female mice. I need to be atleast 95% sure that atleast the pick has 1 male and 1 female. What should be size of the original set to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I think that, for clarity, you should rephrase your question thusly: A set of cardinality/size $N$ has an equal number of males and females. In order to remove (at least/most?) $N/8$ individuals with $95\%$ certainty that the selection has at least $1$ male and at least $1$ female, what is the minimum (maximum?) value of $N$?

Comment: What have you tried? If you pick $n$ mice from a set of $4n$ males and $4n$ females, what is the probability they are all male? all female? a mix?

Comment: Yes, I should have phrased better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the $12.5\%$ pick is random. The tricky part here with low sample size is the change in proportion after each selection (you can't run a z proportion test).

I ran a series of probabilities, $3$ out of $24$, $4$ out of $32$ etc to determine when p went below $.05$. This was at $5$ out of $40$.

Getting no males or no females from a series of $5$ picks with probability  $p<.05$ for $n = 40$ is......

$$2\cdot \frac{20}{40}\cdot \frac{19}{39}\cdot \frac{18}{38}\cdot \frac{17}{37}\cdot \frac{16}{36} = .047$$

Hence randomly sampling $5$ out of $40 (12.5\%)$ has a probability of $<.05$ of not having at least one male and at least one female.

Comment: This is what I got but was not confident. Thank you.